# What SMS can send to switch LED?

Tags: gsm

I have code but I don't know how to send SMS from my Mobile
I mean what the message I can send to switch the Led?
To switch On or Off.
I use SIm900
and use this code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

 char inchar; // Will hold the incoming character from the GSM shield
 SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8);

 int led = 10;

 void setup()
 {
   Serial.begin(19200);
   // set up the digital pins to control
   pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(led, LOW);

   // wake up the GSM shield
   SIM900.begin(19200);
   delay(20000); // give time to log on to network.
   SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); // set SMS mode to text
   delay(100);
   SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
   // blurt out contents of new SMS upon receipt to the GSM shield's serial out
   delay(100);
   Serial.println("Ready...");
 }

 void loop()
 {
   //If a character comes in from the cellular module...
   if(SIM900.available() >0)
   {
     inchar=SIM900.read();
     if (inchar=='#')
     {
       delay(10);

       inchar=SIM900.read();
       if (inchar=='a')
       {
         delay(10);
         inchar=SIM900.read();
         if (inchar=='0')
         {
           digitalWrite(led, LOW);
         }
         else if (inchar=='1')
         {
           digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
         }
         delay(10);
         // SIM900.println("AT+CMGD=1,4"); // delete all SMS
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The code appears to be looking for an SMS that says `#a0` or `#a1`. The logic doesn't look very robust, though. It reads a character, then waits 10ms and tries to read another. What does `SIM900.read()` do if there is no next character? Will it return something? Or wait until there is another? If it waits, the code can get out of sync with incoming, badly-formed commands.